# Почему не работает grid-template-columns я написал код а он не работает

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Магазин продажу пакетів</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/style.css">
  <style>
    .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      background-color: rgb(96, 143, 204);
      border: 1px solid rgb(24, 84, 133);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А что именно у Вас не работает? В Вашем коде отображаются три колонки по 100px каждая, как и указано в ```grid-template-columns```...

Comment: Как бы вы хотели, чтобы выглядел результат кода?

Comment: Не знаю за что ребятам давшим ответы дали по `-1` - ответы у них вполне адекватные в отличие от вопроса (есть и по хуже, но можно было поработать над вопросом прежде чем его публиковать). Прежде чем публиковать такого качества вопросы - внимательно перечитайте его - будет ли он так же понятен тем кто прочтет его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px 15px;
}
.elem {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem">3</div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
  <div class="elem">5</div>
  <div class="elem">6</div>
  <div class="elem">7</div>
  <div class="elem">8</div>
  <div class="elem">9</div>
</div>
```

Без подробного описания проблемы сложно сопоставить ваши ожидания с реальностью. Но, возможно, вы ожидали увидеть подобный результат:

Comment: Да я хотел видеть именно такой результат спасибо

Comment: Рада была помочь!

Comment: А не получалось у вас из-за того, что вы писали padding, вместо grid-gap. + задавали фон контейнеру в целом, а не ячейкам. Поэтому, отступов не видели, очертаний ячеек тоже

Answer (score 0):

ну я не знаю... может потому что смотрите с какого то сферически вакуумного ie5(который о гридах ничего не знает)

---

а может потому что вот тут:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/style.css">
```

явно есть селектор по тяжелее(может и с !important'ом, кто знает...), который и перебивает каскад

разумеется на SO его нету, а потому он(как и результат его действия) присутствующим конечно же не виден.